# Why is `data.map()` function not working as expected when used with data fetched from an API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping, fetch-api

Unable to fix this issue.

Tried `{data?.map(person=>{...}`
and `{data && data.map(person=>{...}`

```js
import {useState} from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({data: []});
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [err, setErr] = useState('');

  const handleClick = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
        },
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Error! status: ${response.status}`);
      }

      const result = await response.json();

      console.log('result is: ', JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));

      setData(result);
    } catch (err) {
      setErr(err.message);
    } finally {]
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  console.log(data);

  return (
    <div>
      {err && <h2>{err}</h2>}

      <button onClick={handleClick}>Fetch data</button>

      {isLoading && <h2>Loading...</h2>}

      {data && data.map((person) => {
        return (
          <div key={person.id}>
            <h2>{person.title}</h2>
            <h2>{person.userId}</h2>
            <br />
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Seems like its an empty array in data.

Tried `{data?.map(person=>{...}`
and `{data && data.map(person=>{...}` how to fix this? Data array feels like empty but how to add data into array from API.

Comment: What exactly is the issue?  If you have an empty array then why specifically do you expect not to have an empty array?  Note also that your *initial* value for `data` is *not* an array, it's an *object*.  Whatever value it updates to after the API call, we can't know.

Comment: for the above code i am getting  error data.map is not a function

Comment: It sounds like this is just a typo then.  This code *should* produce that error on the first render, because `data` is not an array.  Either make it an array or call `.map()` on that object's `data` property (which is an array).  You've essentially confused yourself with your own data structure by naming multiple things "data".

Comment: how to make it an array

Comment: By using an array instead of an object.  So instead of initializing your state to an object here: `useState({data: []})` you'd initialize it to an array: `useState([])`

Comment: I already tried it, that also does not work :(

Comment: "Does not work" tells us exactly nothing about the problem.  Please update the question to indicate the code you're using and the exact problem you're observing when you debug.  If you're getting the same error about `data.map` not being a function then *what is `data`* when that error happens?  How does it differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

I checked the endpoint and it is not an array, map function works only for arrays. If you change your endpoint to fetch all posts `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` it is going to work as expected :)
If what you need is to display post data, using map is totally pointless and your component should return this:

```
return (
          <div key={data.id}>
            <h2>{data.title}</h2>
            <h2>{data.userId}</h2>
            <br />
          </div>
        );
```